# why my questions dont take any attention more?

Tags: discussion

Currently I asked a question and it hasn't received any attention. It is nowadays similalr for all my questions. Currently, only $2$ people visited my question although it is not a bad question at all compared to the others which are currently listed..

Comment: Because two many new/active posts override your question. You can edit repeatedly to make your posts active to take more attentions.

Comment: @HyperGroups i dont think that this could be the main issue. Because previously my questions received alot of attention although I didnt edit repeatedly. Now in the list 'newest' all questions asked after mine and before mine has more views. My question seems like a looser.

Comment: @HyperGroups Constructive edits are fine; repeated needless edits meant to bump the question are not. If noticed, they are likely to attract downvotes (I promise one from me). If the question's score reaches $-4$ or less, the question will no longer appear on the active list, regardless of edits. ... Better ideas include: make sure the tags fit the question; add a bounty after a few days.

Comment: @HyperGroups, in fact, editing serially is something you should **not** do.

Comment: There's nothing wrong, however, with bumping your posts with real corrections, additional thoughts or detail, adding tags, clarifying the title, or improving grammar/spelling/diction/TeX style.  The reason that editing a question bumps it is that attention *should* be drawn to *genuine improvements*.  Rules about repeated edits are intended to prevent abuse of this system, not to discourage edits made in good faith.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

At a guess, the question you refer to is [Comparing the relative entropies of some stochastically ordered distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/432224/5676)

There are two things which provide a disincentive for me to look at that question.

Firstly, the title is using lots of notation, not all of which is familiar to me. On looking at the question, it seems that $D(f|g)$ isn't even standard notation (and you don't use it anywhere in the question, instead using $D(f, g)$!). If you can use a succinct title with minimal notation, and that extremely standard, you might find that fewer people are scared away.

Secondly, when I hover over the question the first words I see are "Question 1". That immediately raises all kinds of negative suspicions. It's probably going to be a long and boring series of questions. The asker might well not have put much effort into distilling out the part they're having trouble with. It might even be someone who wants other people to do their homework.

There are lots of questions and everyone has limited time. If you want your questions to attract attention it's good to have a clear title and a single, clear, question. Showing the motivation of the question and the effort you've put in also help.

Comment: Yes your guess is right and thanks for your answer.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören, you removed the "QUestion 1" and now there is a lonely "Question 2"!

Comment: I think the part which says "If you want your questions to attract attention it's good to have...a single, clear, question" is true, but perhaps miss-leading. If you want to get the best attention possible you *need* the motivation. Indeed, I personally feel that you need to put the motivation first. For example, I like the way that [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139668/is-there-an-infinite-simple-group-with-no-element-of-order-2) question is posed. The OP tells us why the question is interesting *before* stating the question. It grabs your interest, and makes you ponder it...

Comment: @user1729, I also prefer to put the motivation first, but my goal in this answer wasn't to start a debate about the One True Way™ of asking a question. As I see it, I've made four specific recommendations, all of which are uncontroversial.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez yes, i will delete the question 2 part too.

Comment: @user1729 Motivation is also a good idea. I can of course write why it is important.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I just wanted to bang home the motivation! As a question being merely a question is a put-off to many people.

Comment: I added a small motivation as well. I hope it seems better but my initial intention was; if the people were scared of my previous  questions. Because at first hand before deciding to go into question people see my nick name and the title and a bit of the beginning of the question.

Comment: (See [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/proposal-discourage-questions-that-are-nothing-besides-a-problem-statement) meta question for peoples opinions on just stating as question without any background, motivation, or comment of any kind.)

Comment: @user1729 I had originally a comment. I said that I tried and I used one way, but it didnt work out. Thats all from my side for this question, unfortunately)